# SimpleXMLElement: asXML() "on a non-object" that really is an object

Tags: php, xpath, svg, simplexml

I am parsing a SVG file using SimpleXMLElement in PHP. The SVG file is carefully constructed in Adobe Illustrator follow a layer format that I am attempted to dissect.

Consider this code:

```
// Create an XML object out of the SVG
$svg = new SimpleXMLElement('floorplan.svg', null, true);

// Register the SVG namespace
$svg->registerXPathNamespace('svg', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');

// Get the normal floorplan layer
$normal = $svg->xpath('svg:g[@id="Normal"]');

// If the normal layer has content, continue
if(count($normal) > 0) {
  // If there are floors, continue
  if(count($normal[0]->g > 0)) {
    // Loop through each floor
    foreach($normal[0]->g as $floor) {
      // Declare the namespace for the floor
      $floor->registerXPathNamespace('svg', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');

      // Select the base floorplan
      $floorsvg = $floor->xpath('svg:g[@id="Base"]')[0];

      var_dump($floorsvg);
      echo $floorsvg->asXML();  // THIS CAUSES THE ERROR
    }
  }
}
```

When I do a `var_dump` on `$floorsvg`, it is declaring it is a SimpleXMLElement object:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[9]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => string 'Base' (length=4)
  public 'g' => 
    array (size=859)
      0 => ...
```

However, when I run `asXML()` on the object, I am presented with the following PHP error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function asXML() on a non-object

I'm uncertain why `asXML()` is failing, considering it is an object. Can anyone shed any light on why this problem is occurring and what I might try to remedy it?

**EDIT:** Adding an `echo $normal->asXML();` up above results in the same error. It seems like `xpath` is causing the object to become malformed somehow.

**EDIT 2:** The SVG file being parsed can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/zK1yRFA7

Comment: Can you post your SVG file somewhere?

Comment: @SeanBright Sure thing, I've edited my post to a PasteBin dump of the SVG.

Comment: So I had to make the change I suggested in my (now deleted) answer to avoid a syntax error, but once I did that your code works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure how it's working for you. I've recreated the issue on codepad: http://codepad.viper-7.com/sWMKIP

Comment: This works: http://codepad.viper-7.com/BDrxTZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues.  Your code assumes that:

```
$floor->xpath('svg:g[@id="Base"]')
```

Will return an array with at least 1 element.  The `<g id="Second_Floor">` element does not contain any child elements that will be matched by that XPath expression, so trying to access element `0` of an empty array will give you the error you are seeing.

Adding a simple guard expression:

```
// Select the base floorplan
$floorsvg = $floor->xpath('svg:g[@id="Base"]')

if (count($floorsvg) > 0) {
    echo $floorsvg[0]->asXML();
}
```

Will resolve that.  Secondly, you have some misplaced parentheses in this line:

```
if(count($normal[0]->g > 0)) {
```

It should be:

```
if(count($normal[0]->g) > 0) {
```

Appears to be just a simple typo and doesn't appear to affect the outcome of this particular script one way or another.

Comment: Nope, I've tried that. I've also tried moving it down further `$floorsvg[0]->asXML();` No dice.

Comment: OK... third time is the charm.  (I hope)

Comment: You found my overlook! I forgot that the `id` of "Base" is slightly changed in other instances. (e.g. "Base_1_" on the "Second_Floor"). I modified my xpath to look like `svg:g[starts-with(@id, "Base")]` which solved the issue. Thank you for your work (and the discover of my count typo).